# How to get the calculated y value of a tspan or text svg element?

Tags: svg

I need to know the calculated `y` value (vertical baseline position) of each `text` and `tspan`. But writing a function to traverse the tree and compute the calculated `y` value has been complicated.

```
<svg height="500">
<text>
  <tspan x="0" y="17.6">Compare the way things are going in</tspan> 
  <tspan x="0" dy="1.1em">the United States with how they were</tspan> 
  <tspan x="0" y="17.6" dy="1.1em">going five years ago.</tspan>
  <tspan x="0">Something else</tspan>
</text>
</svg>
```

Is there any shortcut for this?

A clearer question might be: "How can I calculate `y` attributes for all texts and tspans that allow me remove all `dy` values and still have the SVG render exactly the same way"?

Note that `getBBox().y` and  `getStartPositionOfChar(n).y` do nor return baseline position.

Comment: Supposing that 1em = 16px you can replace dy="1.1" with the value of the y of the previous tspan (17.6) + 1.1*16 = 35.2

Comment: Thank you. That is a good start. I would like to calculate the y position for any element programatically. That doesn't account for the situations there there is a dy on the element before (which also affects y) or when the element has no y.

Comment: @enxaneta See my own answer for something not pretty but that perhaps solves the problem, came up with it after asking this question

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might work for `y` if the element can be mutated. Something similar could be made for `x`.

```
function calcualteXY(el: SVGTextElement) {
  const dominantBaseline = getAttribute(el, "dominant-baseline");
  const alignmentBaseline = getAttribute(el, "alignment-baseline");
  if (dominantBaseline) el.removeAttribute("dominant-baseline");
  if (alignmentBaseline) el.removeAttribute("alignment-baseline");
  el.setAttribute("y", el.getStartPositionOfChar(0).y.toString());
  if (dominantBaseline) el.setAttribute("dominant-baseline", dominantBaseline);
  if (alignmentBaseline) el.setAttribute("alignment-baseline", alignmentBaseline);
}
```

Comment: This failed when child elements had any of the listed attributes set. It would affect the getStartPosition returned for the parent element

Answer (score 0):

Best attempt so far

```
type ElementWithAttribute = {
  element: Element;
  attribute: keyof typeof svgAttributeToCssStyle;
  value: string;
};

const hAlignAttributes: (keyof typeof svgAttributeToCssStyle)[] = ["text-anchor"];
const vAlignAttributes: (keyof typeof svgAttributeToCssStyle)[] = ["dominant-baseline", "alignment-baseline"];

function calcualteX(svg: SVGSVGElement) {
  const elementsWithAttributes: ElementWithAttribute[] = [];

  for (const attr of hAlignAttributes) {
    const elements = querySelectorAll<SVGElement>(svg, `[${attr}]`);
    for (const element of elements) {
      const val = getAttribute(element, attr);
      if (val !== null) {
        elementsWithAttributes.push({ element, attribute: attr, value: val });
        element.removeAttribute(attr);
      }
    }
  }

  const elements = querySelectorAll<SVGTSpanElement>(svg, `tspan`);
  for (const element of elements) {
    element.setAttribute("x", element.getStartPositionOfChar(0).y.toString());
    element.removeAttribute("dx");
  }

  for (const elementWithAttribute of elementsWithAttributes) {
    elementWithAttribute.element.setAttribute(elementWithAttribute.attribute, elementWithAttribute.value);
  }
}

function calcualteY(svg: SVGSVGElement) {
  const elementsWithAttributes: ElementWithAttribute[] = [];

  for (const attr of vAlignAttributes) {
    const elements = querySelectorAll<SVGElement>(svg, `[${attr}]`);
    for (const element of elements) {
      const val = getAttribute(element, attr);
      if (val !== null) {
        elementsWithAttributes.push({ element, attribute: attr, value: val });
        element.removeAttribute(attr);
      }
    }
  }

  const elements = querySelectorAll<SVGTSpanElement>(svg, `tspan`);
  for (const element of elements) {
    element.setAttribute("y", element.getStartPositionOfChar(0).y.toString());
    element.removeAttribute("dy");
  }

  for (const elementWithAttribute of elementsWithAttributes) {
    elementWithAttribute.element.setAttribute(elementWithAttribute.attribute, elementWithAttribute.value);
  }
}
```