# SVG tspan incorrect position in Chrome/Edge but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working with a SVG element which contains a text element with the following structure

```
    <g class="textGroup2">
          <text class="split0" x="640" y="80" dy="0" stroke="black">
            <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="0" style="font-size: xx-large;">S</tspan>
            <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="1" style="font-size: xx-large;">V</tspan>
            <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="2" style="font-size: xx-large;">G</tspan>
          </text>
      </g>
```

I am trying to provide an `x` and `y` attribute to each of the tspan by doing this

```
    document.querySelectorAll('body > svg > g.textGroup2 > text[class^="split"]>tspan').forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        const dim = a.getStartPositionOfChar(0);
        a.setAttribute('x', `${dim.x}`);
        a.setAttribute('y', `${dim.y}`);
        a.removeAttribute('alignment-baseline');
    });
```

As a result, **Firefox** returns this,
[image: Firefox]

whereas **Chrome/Edge** returns this
[image: Chrome/Edge]

How can I make Chrome/Edge returns what Firefox returns, i.e. each tspan with `x` and constant `y` attribute? The full code is following

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('body > svg > g.textGroup2 > text[class^="split"]>tspan').forEach(
(a, i) => {
    const dim = a.getStartPositionOfChar(0); 
    a.setAttribute('x', `${dim.x}`);
    a.setAttribute('y', `${dim.y}`);
    a.removeAttribute('alignment-baseline');
});
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
      <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
      <g class="textGroup2">
          <text class="split0" x="640" y="80" dy="0" stroke="black">
            <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="0" style="font-size: xx-large;">S</tspan>
            <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="1" style="font-size: xx-large;">V</tspan>
            <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="2" style="font-size: xx-large;">G</tspan>
          </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I would have to look, but I think there is a report on git about how tspans are not working properly. There was a suggestion, but I don't remember there ever being a definitive "fix". I will have to look around.

Comment: If I remember correctly, they suggest just using a straight `<text>` element - without a `<tspan>`. Maybe a text element for each `<tspan>`.

Comment: Okay. So I checked the output from the javascript code you gave - the y value stays the same from firefox as it is initially, while chrome computes it properly. You should check out this link maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63943963/how-to-get-the-calculated-y-value-of-a-tspan-or-text-svg-element

Comment: Firefox does not support alignment-baseline. maybe chrome will work like Firefox if you remove that attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to remove `alignment-baseline="hanging"` from `<tspan/>` or if you need this attribute initially, you can remove it in a loop before determining the position of `<tspan/>`.

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('body > svg > g.textGroup2 > text[class^="split"]>tspan')
  .forEach((a, i) => {
    a.removeAttribute('alignment-baseline');
    const dim = a.getStartPositionOfChar(0);
    a.setAttribute('x', `${dim.x}`);
    a.setAttribute('y', `${dim.y}`);
  });
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 720">
  <rect class="vBoxRect" width="1280" height="720" fill="#EFEFEF"></rect>
  <g class="textGroup2">
    <text class="split0" x="640" y="80" dy="0" stroke="black">
      <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="0" style="font-size: xx-large">S</tspan>
      <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="1" style="font-size: xx-large">V</tspan>
      <tspan alignment-baseline="hanging" data-t="2" style="font-size: xx-large">G</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Aren't the letters supposed to be staggered vertically? This is not the case for me in chrome 104.0.5112.81 nor Firefox 84.0.1. Where as the OP staggers the letters - at least for me.